# syntax error coming while execute the query

Tags: sql

```
select count(*) as distinctname from
 (select distinct nationalityname from dbo.profile)
```

Comment: Don't you think you should tell us what the error is?  [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Valid ANSI/ISO SQL, but perhaps your dbms has some restrictions. Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an alias for your subqueries

```
select count(*) as distinctname from
 (select distinct nationalityname from dbo.profile) alias_name
```

or make it simpler like this

```
select count(distinct nationalityname) from dbo.profile
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give alias to sub-query

```
select count(*) as distinctname 
  from (select distinct nationalityname 
          from dbo.profile) t -- this is alias
```

In SQL Server, You need to give alias to sub-queries used in `FROM` clause.